# replace values in one dataframe with boolean conditions from another dataframe in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I have below two dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True, False, True], 'B': [False, True, False]})
```

when I try to mask df1 using Boolean condition from df2 as below

```
df3 = df1.mask(df2)
```

I get output as

```
>>> df3
     A    B   C
0  NaN  4.0 NaN
1  2.0  NaN NaN
2  NaN  6.0 NaN
```

But I want to ignore column C since this column doesn't exist in df2 and also show values as original
My desired output is as below

```
>>> df3
     A    B   C
0   NaN  4    7
1   2    NaN  8
2   NaN  6    9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) before masking:

```
out = df1.mask(df2.reindex_like(df1).fillna(False))
```

Or:

```
out = df1.mask(df2.reindex(columns=df1.columns, fill_value=False))
```

Output:

```
     A    B  C
0  NaN  4.0  7
1  2.0  NaN  8
2  NaN  6.0  9
```

Comment: something i was looking for !..also is there way to show original values like 2 instead of 2.0 ?

Comment: You can cover to Int64 with `.astype('Int64')`

Comment: @mozway. Hello ! Happy new year :-) I'm just here temporary ! gg for you reputation !!! Awesome.